# AutoMapper with ValueFormatter

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-2

I'm learning how to use AutoMapper, and I'm having problems using it with ValueFormatter.

Here's simple example in Console, where I'm unable to use it with NameFormatter:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<ExampleProfile>());

        var person = new Person {FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith"};

        PersonView oV = Mapper.Map<Person, PersonView>(person);

        Console.WriteLine(oV.Name);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ExampleProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        //works:
        //CreateMap<Person, PersonView>()
        //    .ForMember(personView => personView.Name, ex => ex.MapFrom(
        //        person => person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName));

        //doesn't work:
        CreateMap<Person, PersonView>()
            .ForMember(personView => personView.Name, 
             person => person.AddFormatter<NameFormatter>());
    }
}

public class NameFormatter : ValueFormatter<Person>
{
    protected override string FormatValueCore(Person value)
    {
        return value.FirstName + " " + value.LastName;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing here? AutoMapper is version 2.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `ValueResolver` (some more infos [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers)) :

```
public class PersonNameResolver : ValueResolver<Person, string>
{
    protected override string ResolveCore(Person value)
    {
        return (value == null ? string.Empty : value.FirstName + " " + value.LastName);
    }
}
```

and your profile should be something like this:

```
public class ExampleProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Person, PersonView>()
            .ForMember(personView => personView.Name, person => person.ResolveUsing<PersonNameResolver>());
    }
}
```

According to the author `Formatters` are for global type conversions. You can read some of his replies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2180606/219406) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1667381/219406).

I would go for the first of your options:

```
 CreateMap<Person, PersonView>()
      .ForMember(personView => personView.Name, ex => ex.MapFrom(
           person => person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName));
```

And apparently value formatters have been a [mistake](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-formatters).

Comment: thanks, this is working, but the obvious question is why with resolver and not formatter?

Comment: Thanks again. I should use more recent book for my study obviously ;)